# Login Handlers authentication methods in Shibboleth

Tags: java, authentication, shibboleth

I am using the following login handlers in the handler.xml file, I don't know why these many login:Handlers
are supported, As i know that, we are using "externalAuthn" Login handler but i don't know why we are using
the remainng handlers. May i know that should we use remaining remote user and ipaddress along with
the ExternalAuthN.

```
Handler.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ph:ProfileHandlerGroup xmlns:ph="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:idp:profile-handler" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:idp:profile-handler classpath:/schema/shibboleth-2.0-idp-profile-handler.xsd">

    <!-- Error Handler -->
    <ph:ErrorHandler xsi:type="ph:JSPErrorHandler" jspPagePath="/error.jsp"/>

    <!-- Profile Handlers -->
    <!-- 
        All profile handlers defined below are accessed via the Servlet path "/profile" so if your profile 
        handler's request path is "/Status" then the full path is "<servletContextName>/profile/Status"
     -->
    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:Status">
        <ph:RequestPath>/Status</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAMLMetadata" metadataFile="D:/SDC-Builds/SRDM2.3.0.6904.10/SRDM/Svr/IdP/IdPserver/metadata/idp-metadata.xml">
        <ph:RequestPath>/Metadata/SAML</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>    

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:ShibbolethSSO" inboundBinding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01">
        <ph:RequestPath>/Shibboleth/SSO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML1AttributeQuery" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding"
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML1/SOAP/AttributeQuery</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML1ArtifactResolution" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:bindings:SOAP-binding">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML1/SOAP/ArtifactResolution</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <!-- urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign -->
    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SSO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/POST/SSO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SSO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SSO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SSO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/Redirect/SSO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SSO" inboundBinding="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:profiles:AuthnRequest" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/Unsolicited/SSO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2ECP" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/SOAP/ECP</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SLO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/Redirect/SLO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SLO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/POST/SLO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SLO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
                                                   urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign/SLO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SLO" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/SOAP/SLO</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2SLO" inboundBinding="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:profiles:LocalLogout">
        <ph:RequestPath>/Logout</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2AttributeQuery" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/SOAP/AttributeQuery</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <ph:ProfileHandler xsi:type="ph:SAML2ArtifactResolution" inboundBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" 
                       outboundBindingEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP">
        <ph:RequestPath>/SAML2/SOAP/ArtifactResolution</ph:RequestPath>
    </ph:ProfileHandler>

    <!-- Login Handlers -->
    <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:RemoteUser">
        <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
    </ph:LoginHandler>

    <!-- Login handler that delegates the act of authentication to an external system. -->
    <!-- This login handler and the RemoteUser login handler will be merged in the next major release. -->
    <!--
    <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:ExternalAuthn">
        <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
        <ph:QueryParam name="foo" value="bar" />
    </ph:LoginHandler>
    -->
   <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:ExternalAuthn"
                 externalAuthnPath="/external/login"
                 supportsForcedAuthentication="true" >
    <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
</ph:LoginHandler>

   <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:IPAddress" username="ip-user" defaultDeny="true">
    <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:InternetProtocol</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
    <ph:IPEntry>127.0.0.1/16</ph:IPEntry>
</ph:LoginHandler>
    <!-- 
    <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:IPAddress" username="ip-user" defaultDeny="true">
    <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:InternetProtocol</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
    <ph:IPEntry>127.0.0.1/16</ph:IPEntry>
</ph:LoginHandler>  -->
    <!-- 
        Removal of this login handler will disable SSO support, that is it will require the user to authenticate 
        on every request.
         <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:PreviousSession">
        <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PreviousSession</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
    </ph:LoginHandler>

     <ph:LoginHandler xsi:type="ph:PreviousSession">
        <ph:AuthenticationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PreviousSession</ph:AuthenticationMethod>
    </ph:LoginHandler>
   -->

</ph:ProfileHandlerGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

The external login handler is intended for 'container auth' -- usually, some form of basic auth in Apache protecting `/external/login` and populating `REMOTE_USER` which is then read by the IdP. The only other auth mechanism you probably care about is the previous session one, which is what actually enables SSO to happen.

For what it's worth, by default, there's a big XML comment around most of those when you start with a fresh copy of the IdP configuration file. Maybe you're overlooking that they are actually already disabled?

Comment: Thank you @Martin, Since i am new to this shibboleth as well as SSO, I am not getting proper clarification. I checked that my app is working by taking away "ph:RemoteUser" and 'ph:IpAddress'. I am thinking that that is unnecessary code which we have put in the handler.xml, As per my understanding other(ipaddress, remoteuser) is not used in my app. but you are saying remoteUser also is used at Idp side. We have commented the previousSession in xml file

Comment: You'd need to show us the whole file to be able to check if the handlers are commented out or not. But in general, you don't need the external login handler unless you are doing container auth.

Comment: Hello @Martin, Please look into my whole handler.xml which is with commented and used code in our application.

Comment: Hello @User, it definitely looks like someone un-commented those from the default. Check out [the original version of that file](http://svn.shibboleth.net/view/java-shib-idp2/trunk/src/installer/resources/conf-tmpl/handler.xml?view=markup). You can probably comment out all the handlers except the external authn one. Btw, this is easy to test (you do have a test system, right?), so just try it -- the minimum number of login handlers you need is 1.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, what about previous session which has a comment that it is mandatory to use it, that also we have commented out.

Comment: PreviousSession is only mandatory if you want sessions to be re-used on subsequent visits. Turning it off will break SSO (every login attempt will yield a new login prompt), but won't break authentication in general.

Comment: thank you @Martin, we are not using previous session concept but we are able to authenticate user by using shibboleth sso.